# Strange behavior adding color to geom_label in ggplot

Tags: r, ggplot2

I have a script that downloads a bunch of COVID testing data and plots it.  For purposes of reproducibility I have a big dput() to go straight to the plotting data.

```
    library(ggplot2)  
    library(dplyr)    
    library(tidyr)    
    library(stringr)  
    library(gtable)
    library(cowplot)
    library(ggrepel)

    maxDate <- "2020-05-26"

    my_dates <- function(d) {
      seq( d[1] + (wday(maxDate) - wday(d[1])+1) %% 7, d[2] + 6, by = "week")
    }

    stateWeekly <- structure(list(weekStarting = structure(c(18353, 18360, 18367, 
            18374, 18381, 18388, 18395, 18402, 18353, 18360, 18367, 18374, 
            18381, 18388, 18395, 18402, 18353, 18360, 18367, 18374, 18381, 
            18388, 18395, 18402, 18353, 18360, 18367, 18374, 18381, 18388, 
            18395, 18402, 18353, 18360, 18367, 18374, 18381, 18388, 18395, 
            18402, 18353, 18360, 18367, 18374, 18381, 18388, 18395, 18402, 
            18353, 18360, 18367, 18374, 18381, 18388, 18395, 18402, 18353, 
            18360, 18367, 18374, 18381, 18388, 18395, 18402, 18353, 18360, 
            18367, 18374, 18381, 18388, 18395, 18402), class = "Date"), posInc = c(405L, 
            659L, 626L, 852L, 1208L, 1038L, 1027L, 930L, 1899L, 1685L, 1571L, 
            2658L, 3638L, 2421L, 2267L, 2587L, 8383L, 7473L, 9923L, 11770L, 
            11181L, 13170L, 12413L, 14938L, 4889L, 5405L, 5658L, 4734L, 5096L, 
            4924L, 4086L, 5009L, 907L, 712L, 623L, 603L, 717L, 605L, 757L, 
            648L, 851L, 674L, 884L, 1047L, 1106L, 983L, 952L, 1236L, 2583L, 
            2498L, 6445L, 2403L, 4841L, 4281L, 3702L, 4054L, 8409L, 6620L, 
            6128L, 5351L, 4593L, 4484L, 5021L, 5311L, 8583L, 13005L, 15059L, 
            15134L, 11969L, 9061L, 8593L, 5768L), totInc = c(9298L, 10145L, 
            6785L, 20048L, 22917L, 25001L, 30899L, 39741L, 25514L, 25957L, 
            29351L, 53746L, 56934L, 64962L, 62299L, 57381L, 101975L, 70979L, 
            97892L, 277508L, 202294L, 253468L, 305946L, 357080L, 17532L, 
            28082L, 26345L, 51880L, 60863L, 61296L, 115977L, 136789L, 11499L, 
            14976L, 16075L, 15355L, 19718L, 16694L, 43036L, 20794L, 16134L, 
            11829L, 25882L, 30081L, 24276L, 26770L, 20537L, 24570L, 21647L, 
            17163L, 26713L, 27992L, 38029L, 56996L, 59871L, 61798L, 77539L, 
            65018L, 73879L, 89816L, 98816L, 113913L, 136251L, 207369L, 34413L, 
            45555L, 57683L, 69888L, 78849L, 68147L, 75444L, 68541L), posRate = c(4.35577543557754, 
            6.49581074420897, 9.22623434045689, 4.24980047885076, 5.2711960553301, 
            4.15183392664293, 3.32373215961682, 2.34015248735563, 7.44297248569413, 
            6.49150518164657, 5.35245817859698, 4.94548431511182, 6.38985491973162, 
            3.72679412579662, 3.63890271111896, 4.50846098882906, 8.22064231429272, 
            10.5284661660491, 10.1366812405508, 4.24131916917711, 5.52710411579187, 
            5.19592216768981, 4.05725193334771, 4.18337627422426, 27.8861510381018, 
            19.2472046150559, 21.4765610172708, 9.12490362374711, 8.37290307740335, 
            8.03315061341686, 3.52311234124007, 3.6618441541352, 7.88764240368728, 
            4.7542735042735, 3.8755832037325, 3.92705958971019, 3.63627142712243, 
            3.62405654726249, 1.75899247141928, 3.11628354332981, 5.27457543076732, 
            5.69786118860428, 3.41550112046982, 3.4806023735913, 4.55594002306805, 
            3.67202091893911, 4.63553586210255, 5.03052503052503, 11.9323693814385, 
            14.5545650527297, 24.1268296335118, 8.5845955987425, 12.7297588682321, 
            7.51105340725665, 6.1832940822769, 6.56008285057769, 10.8448651646268, 
            10.181795810391, 8.29464394482871, 5.95773581544491, 4.64803270725389, 
            3.93633738028144, 3.68511056799583, 2.56113498160284, 24.9411559585041, 
            28.5479091208429, 26.1064785118666, 21.6546474358974, 15.1796471737118, 
            13.2962566217148, 11.3899050951699, 8.4154010008608), dailyTest = c(0.221715743153114, 
            0.241912907538001, 0.161791924854149, 0.478055196680321, 0.546468023858884, 
            0.596162109547321, 0.736803048794155, 0.947645230011603, 0.186801507766532, 
            0.190044945406282, 0.214894217075154, 0.393502933151213, 0.416843969709953, 
            0.475621209827133, 0.45612397634033, 0.420116693468346, 0.12904234722506, 
            0.0898190415659478, 0.123875591611234, 0.35116728309617, 0.255989140373094, 
            0.320746316905531, 0.387153615730504, 0.451860175014704, 0.0825624070925685, 
            0.132244895960159, 0.124064944949448, 0.244315404971621, 0.286618513739163, 
            0.288657614941027, 0.546163602975976, 0.644172319403682, 0.145300534171213, 
            0.189235655252465, 0.2031225399428, 0.194024671901816, 0.249155225044611, 
            0.210944179272479, 0.543799790294142, 0.262751483394748, 0.251625255227923, 
            0.184484637665247, 0.403654695413976, 0.46914214097627, 0.378607580011965, 
            0.417503909907741, 0.320294277092838, 0.383192792918685, 0.0925948105499996, 
            0.0734145485965558, 0.114264571267249, 0.119735480062622, 0.162668640015057, 
            0.243799779281553, 0.25609756097561, 0.264340282827592, 0.180510171998102, 
            0.151361384116027, 0.171989721263465, 0.209090929831202, 0.230042857867195, 
            0.265188553151573, 0.317191238536909, 0.482753373877332, 0.24964080537941, 
            0.330467756053207, 0.418447405826301, 0.506985633520943, 0.571991045923375, 
            0.494355969086992, 0.547290294977021, 0.497214147023222), state = c("NM (cum 4.2%)", 
            "NM (cum 4.2%)", "NM (cum 4.2%)", "NM (cum 4.2%)", "NM (cum 4.2%)", 
            "NM (cum 4.2%)", "NM (cum 4.2%)", "NM (cum 4.2%)", "TN (cum 3%)", 
            "TN (cum 3%)", "TN (cum 3%)", "TN (cum 3%)", "TN (cum 3%)", "TN (cum 3%)", 
            "TN (cum 3%)", "TN (cum 3%)", "*CA (cum 2.1%)", "*CA (cum 2.1%)", 
            "*CA (cum 2.1%)", "*CA (cum 2.1%)", "*CA (cum 2.1%)", "*CA (cum 2.1%)", 
            "*CA (cum 2.1%)", "*CA (cum 2.1%)", "*GA (cum 2.4%)", "*GA (cum 2.4%)", 
            "*GA (cum 2.4%)", "*GA (cum 2.4%)", "*GA (cum 2.4%)", "*GA (cum 2.4%)", 
            "*GA (cum 2.4%)", "*GA (cum 2.4%)", "*OK (cum 2%)", "*OK (cum 2%)", 
            "*OK (cum 2%)", "*OK (cum 2%)", "*OK (cum 2%)", "*OK (cum 2%)", 
            "*OK (cum 2%)", "*OK (cum 2%)", "UT (cum 3.1%)", "UT (cum 3.1%)", 
            "UT (cum 3.1%)", "UT (cum 3.1%)", "UT (cum 3.1%)", "UT (cum 3.1%)", 
            "UT (cum 3.1%)", "UT (cum 3.1%)", "OH (cum 1.5%)", "OH (cum 1.5%)", 
            "OH (cum 1.5%)", "OH (cum 1.5%)", "OH (cum 1.5%)", "OH (cum 1.5%)", 
            "OH (cum 1.5%)", "OH (cum 1.5%)", "FL (cum 2.1%)", "FL (cum 2.1%)", 
            "FL (cum 2.1%)", "FL (cum 2.1%)", "FL (cum 2.1%)", "FL (cum 2.1%)", 
            "FL (cum 2.1%)", "FL (cum 2.1%)", "*MA (cum 4%)", "*MA (cum 4%)", 
            "*MA (cum 4%)", "*MA (cum 4%)", "*MA (cum 4%)", "*MA (cum 4%)", 
            "*MA (cum 4%)", "*MA (cum 4%)"), cumPos = c(686L, 1345L, 1971L, 
            2823L, 4031L, 5069L, 6096L, 7026L, 4137L, 5822L, 7393L, 10051L, 
            13689L, 16110L, 18377L, 20964L, 15812L, 23285L, 33208L, 44978L, 
            56159L, 69329L, 81742L, 96680L, 8816L, 14221L, 19879L, 24613L, 
            29709L, 34633L, 38719L, 43728L, 1471L, 2183L, 2806L, 3409L, 4126L, 
            4731L, 5488L, 6136L, 1737L, 2411L, 3295L, 4342L, 5448L, 6431L, 
            7383L, 8619L, 4782L, 7280L, 13725L, 16128L, 20969L, 25250L, 28952L, 
            33006L, 14745L, 21365L, 27493L, 32844L, 37437L, 41921L, 46942L, 
            52253L, 15096L, 28101L, 43160L, 58294L, 70263L, 79324L, 87917L, 
            93685L), cumTot = c(21809L, 31954L, 38739L, 58787L, 81704L, 106705L, 
            137604L, 177345L, 52873L, 78830L, 108181L, 161927L, 218861L, 
            283823L, 346122L, 403503L, 130714L, 201693L, 299585L, 577093L, 
            779387L, 1032855L, 1338801L, 1695881L, 33711L, 61793L, 88138L, 
            140018L, 200881L, 262177L, 378154L, 514943L, 13292L, 28268L, 
            44343L, 59698L, 79416L, 96110L, 139146L, 159940L, 34646L, 46475L, 
            72357L, 102438L, 126714L, 153484L, 174021L, 198591L, 50831L, 
            67994L, 94707L, 122699L, 160728L, 217724L, 277595L, 339393L, 
            138136L, 203154L, 277033L, 366849L, 465665L, 579578L, 715829L, 
            923198L, 81366L, 126921L, 184604L, 254492L, 333341L, 401488L, 
            476932L, 545473L), cumRate = c(3.14549039387409, 4.20917569005445, 
            5.08789591884148, 4.80208209297974, 4.93366297855674, 4.75048029614357, 
            4.43010377605302, 3.96176943246215, 7.82440943392658, 7.38551312951922, 
            6.83391723130679, 6.2071180223187, 6.25465478088833, 5.67607276365904, 
            5.30939957587209, 5.19550040520145, 12.0966384625977, 11.5447734923869, 
            11.0846671228533, 7.7938911059396, 7.20553460604295, 6.71236524003853, 
            6.10561240991006, 5.70087170031388, 26.1517012251194, 23.0139336170764, 
            22.5544033220631, 17.5784541987459, 14.7893529004734, 13.2097781269905, 
            10.2389502689381, 8.49181365704554, 11.0668071020163, 7.72251308900524, 
            6.32794353110976, 5.71040905892995, 5.19542661428428, 4.92248465300177, 
            3.9440587584264, 3.83643866449919, 5.01356577959938, 5.1877353415815, 
            4.55380958303965, 4.23866143423339, 4.29944599649605, 4.19001329128769, 
            4.24259141138138, 4.34007583425231, 9.40764494107926, 10.706827072977, 
            14.4920650004751, 13.1443614047384, 13.0462644965407, 11.5972515662031, 
            10.4295826653938, 9.72500906029294, 10.674263045115, 10.5166523917816, 
            9.92408846599503, 8.95300246150324, 8.0394704347546, 7.23302126719786, 
            6.5577114087303, 5.65999926342995, 18.5532040409999, 22.1405441179947, 
            23.3797750861303, 22.90602455087, 21.0784151964505, 19.757502092217, 
            18.4338647857556, 17.1750022457574)), row.names = c(NA, -72L), class = c("tbl_df", 
            "tbl", "data.frame"))

  USAWeekly <- structure(list(weekStarting = structure(c(18353, 18360, 18367, 
        18374, 18381, 18388, 18395, 18402), class = "Date"), posInc = c(203510L, 
        208864L, 200025L, 204005L, 189367L, 166078L, 158519L, 149783L
        ), totInc = c(1009914L, 1031868L, 1055315L, 1635742L, 1747039L, 
        2103855L, 2533954L, 2704229L), posRate = c(20.1512207970184, 
        20.2413486996399, 18.9540563717942, 12.4717100863095, 10.8393115437034, 
        7.89398508927659, 6.25579627728049, 5.53884304916485), dailyTest = c(0.307675928471295, 
        0.314364336923558, 0.321507596146488, 0.498337916485456, 0.532245167806925, 
        0.640951150785093, 0.771983208128169, 0.823858435841073), state = c("USA tested 4.5%", 
        "USA tested 4.5%", "USA tested 4.5%", "USA tested 4.5%", "USA tested 4.5%", 
        "USA tested 4.5%", "USA tested 4.5%", "USA tested 4.5%"), cumPos = c(394280L, 
        603144L, 803169L, 1007174L, 1196541L, 1362619L, 1521138L, 1670921L
        ), cumTot = c(2093900L, 3125768L, 4181083L, 5816825L, 7563864L, 
        9667719L, 12201673L, 14905902L), cumRate = c(18.8299345718516, 
        19.2958658480092, 19.2095923472459, 17.3148410000301, 15.8191765478597, 
        14.0945242616174, 12.4666346983729, 11.2097946169242)), row.names = c(NA, 
        -8L), class = c("tbl_df", "tbl", "data.frame"))


            #background layer
            bg <- USAWeekly %>%
              select(-state)

            #endpoint layer
            endpoints <- stateWeekly %>% 
              group_by(state) %>%
              filter(weekStarting == max(weekStarting)) %>%
              select(weekStarting, posRate, state, cumRate) %>%
              ungroup()

            g <- stateWeekly %>% ggplot(aes(x = as.Date(weekStarting))) +
              geom_col(aes(y=100*dailyTest), size=0.75, color="darkblue", fill="white") +
              geom_line(aes(y=cumRate), size = 0.75, color="red") +
              geom_point(data = endpoints,size = 1.5,shape = 21,
                         aes(color = "red", fill = "red", y = cumRate), show.legend = FALSE) +
              geom_label(data=endpoints, aes(label=paste(round(cumRate,1),"%",sep=""), y = cumRate), 
                         show.legend = FALSE, 
                         nudge_y = 12) +
              scale_y_continuous(name = "Cum Test Positivity Rate", 
                                 sec.axis = sec_axis(~./100, name="Weekly % of Pop Tested")) +
       scale_x_date(breaks = my_dates, date_labels = "%b %d") +
       labs(x = "Week Starting") +
       theme(plot.title = element_text(size = rel(1), face = "bold"),
              plot.subtitle = element_text(size = rel(0.7)),
              plot.caption = element_text(size = rel(1)),
              axis.text.y = element_text(color='red'),
              axis.title.y = element_text(color="red"),
              axis.text.y.right = element_text(color="blue"),
              axis.title.y.right = element_text(color="blue"),
              axis.text.x = element_text(angle = 45,hjust = 1),
              strip.background =element_rect(fill="white"),
              strip.text = element_text(colour = 'blue')) +
        facet_wrap(~ state)


print(g)
```

This works fine and produces the following chart

[image]

I was then asked to make the text in the labels the same color as the line.  I thought that I could accomplish that by changing

```
geom_label(data=endpoints, aes(label=paste(round(cumRate,1),"%",sep=""), y = cumRate), 
             show.legend = FALSE, 
             nudge_y = 12)
```

to this

```
geom_label(data=endpoints, aes(label=paste(round(cumRate,1),"%",sep=""), 
                                 y = cumRate, 
                                 color="red"), 
             show.legend = FALSE, 
             nudge_y = 12)
```

basically just adding `color="red"` in the `aes()` for the `geom_label`

But that produces this chart

[image]

Where the text looks...orange?  I've tried a number of other reds (darkred, firebrick, etc) and I always get the weird orange. I also get a warning message when the code runs

`In match(x, table, nomatch = 0L) : reached elapsed time limit`

Any ideas on what I need to do differently?

Comment: Can't run your code: `my_dates` not found, `USAWeekly` not found.

Comment: What happens if you add the color outside the aes() for geom_label?

Comment: Apologies...forgot some things were still in the environment when I skinnied the code down.  Above should work now.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When you include `color=` within `aes(...)`, it is trying to find meaningful factors in that assignment. `aes(color="red")` finds that the vector assigned is: (1) not a symbol indicating a column in the data, and (2) contains one unique value (regardless of its actual value), so does the standard thing of assigning the next color from the chosen palette.

Two ways to work with this:

1. Bring `color=` outside `aes`, as in

   ```r
   geom_label(data=endpoints,
              aes(label=paste(round(cumRate,1),"%",sep=""), 
                  y = cumRate),
              color="red",
              show.legend = FALSE, 
              nudge_y = 12)
   ```
2. Or tell `ggplot2::aes` you mean the literal (`I`dentity) color `"red"`:

   ```r
   geom_label(data=endpoints,
              aes(label=paste(round(cumRate,1),"%",sep=""), 
                  y = cumRate, color=I("red")), 
              show.legend = FALSE, 
              nudge_y = 12)
   ```